# Use Polymer Custom Element in a Java web project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, polymer

I want to start using Polymer in my Java webapp so I want to start developing some Polymer Custom Element and use them in my simple Java project. How to do that? It seem I have to use bower and tools like that but I want just to give devlopper to make a custom element... So how to integrate the custome element with the imports and the paths?

Just a last question: Is there a way to protect all my html files only for my registred users access?

Thx for help

Comment: I'm not sure if it's impossible, but it's probably infeasible. You might as well switch fully from Java to a JavaScript environment for web development.

Polymer is a client-side JavaScript library, so you'd have to run your Java app on the client, and that client must be able to execute JavaScript (e.g., with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)).

Answer (score 0):

By java webapp I'm assuming you mean a server side app, with some jsp or jsf to render the front part.

To use polymer elements in this, you just have to put the polymer librairies in a static folder, and import it in your web page (the same way you would do it with jquery, for example)
Bower and the likes are here to simplify the use of many elements, and theirs interdependances, they will just dl the files and put it in a specified folder, without interacting with your java code. But if you plan on using mostly custom elements, you can try to do it by hand.

Either way just think of it like a static ressource, and it will be good.

For bringing your datas in the elements you can either create some json webservices, and use ajax (iron-ajax element is good, or another method can also work) to retrieve it, or create a java string variable containing the datas in json, and bind it in the element in jsf, jsp, etc...

Comment: Yes it's about my server-side code. How to modify the URLs call to my static directory simply in the web.xml file? Do I have to use the Polymer CLI?

Comment: polymer CLI is just here to automate some things, like creating a new element with doc and unit test. There is no obligation to use it. Polymer is just static html, so you juste have to use it like you would with static html.

Comment: ok , and how i deal with dependencies? do i have to rewrite all of theme (i mean the uri on html import and script call)?

Comment: I can't be specific without seeing your whole projects, but it is possible that you'll to rewrite all or some of them.

Comment: I'm speaking about the way to redirect urls to static directory like here in pyhton:

`handlers:

- url: /

  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html` but using the web.xml file